# "Folder of folder" in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make a .htaccess redirect to some webpages as usual.
Here's  how I got it working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Profile/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=profile&username=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=profile&username=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^Profile/Me index.php?page=profile [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Profile/me index.php?page=profile [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/Me index.php?page=profile [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/me index.php?page=profile [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^Personagem/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=personagem&personagem=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^personagem/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=personagem&personagem=$1 [NC,L]
```

And here is what I need: When I'm on "Personagem" page, I can access all "Albums", on the following URL:

```
/Personagem/--name of character--/Album
```

Being, `--name of character--`, the parameter of `/Personagem`. Is it possible?

Comment: Who wrote the existing RewriteRules then? Why don't you just duplicate the last one and add `/Album` to the pattern? Why are all rules duplicated with different casing even though they use `[NC]` already?

Comment: Copied/pasted code. I have mo idea what "MC,L" meas yet :(

Comment: And if I copied/paste the last one, my 'Personagem' name parameteter wwould be "name/Album", insted of "name"

Comment: Yes, ordering is crucial with RewriteRules. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=profile&username=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/me index.php?page=profile [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^personagem/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=personagem&personagem=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^personagem/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=personagem&personagem=$1&album=$2 [NC,L]
```

You can add other with:

```
RewriteRule ^personagem/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=personagem&personagem=$1&album=$2&other=$3 [NC,L]
```

No need to add PrOfILE or PROfILe... with NC (no case)

Comment: In that case, would the URL be  like "/Personagem/Name/1" instead of "/Personagem/Name/Album/1"?

Comment: Yes. Would you like an `/Album/` folder in addition ?